# Django methodSerializer doesnt return absolute image url

Tags: django

Serializer.py

```
class PostImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PostImage
        fields = ('id', 'post', 'post_img')

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    postimg_set = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_postimg_set')
    editor = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'content', 'editor', 'postimg_set', 'created_at')

    def get_postimg_set(self, obj):
        a = PostImage.objects.filter(post = obj.id)
        print(a[0].post_img)
        return PostImageSerializer(a, many=True).data
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import os, uuid, datetime
from apps.account.models import *
from django.utils import timezone

def img_upload(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    path = "media/static/post/{}".format(instance.post.id)
    format = uuid.uuid4().hex + "_" + filename
    return os.path.join(path, format)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('제목', null=False, blank=False, max_length=40)
    content = models.TextField('내용', null=False, blank=False)
    editor = models.ForeignKey(User, default = 1, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="작성자", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.localtime())
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = '게시글'
        verbose_name_plural = '게시글'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_img = models.ImageField(upload_to=img_upload)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "게시글 이미지"
        verbose_name_plural = "게시글 이미지"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.post.title) + "이미지"
```

[image: this is result.]

Guess postimg_set = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_postimg_set') is not return absolute URL for the images. When I use UserSerializer(), it returned absolute image url of User's profile image.

Looking for help. Thank you

Comment: in your urls.py add: urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Answer (score 0):

In your `urls.py`, Add:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) 
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
-- closed--
```